# Cannot connect to mysql what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection

Any help appreciated, not sure if I'm just super tired or blind, but I can't figure out why my database is not connecting. Here is part of my code. I didn't realize it wasn't connecting until I ran my init() function within the connection.connect and it didn't work and I didnt even get an error message. I had been running it outside and it was fine.

I'm using the printTable npm package which I added to my requirements and I also did not include the init() function.

```
// Connects to database + .env for password privacy
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        port: PORT,
        database: "employees",
        // Added connectTimeout due to frequent ._handleTimeoutError
        connectTimeout: 300000
    },
    console.log("Connected to Employee Tracker")
);

// Check for connection errors
connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to Employee Database');
    init();
});

function viewDepts() {
    // Expected Behavior: Show dept names + Ids
    // console.log("Viewing all departments");
    connection.query(`select * from department`, function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        printTable(res);
        init();
    })
};
```

I just ran

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME
```

and nothing seemed out of the ordinary

Comment: Are you able to connect locally via terminal using the username password?

Comment: Yep! I have it connected & I can see the tables in command line when I do queries, it just won't work when I run my application with node.js